# This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit. - Does this affect me negatively?

Tags: support

I understand why my edit was rejected when this rejection occurs - (This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.) But, does this affect me negatively where if having too many I could lose edit privileges?

Comment: Summary: nope, conflicting edits can't lead to an edit ban and don't negatively affect you (except for possibly needing to re-edit, of course). The dupe addresses two distinct types of community rejections, though, and the other (author rejecting) does count.