# Edits that conflict with a subsequent edit should not count as rejected edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I had a [good suggested-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27292738) rejected because *"This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit"*. Fair enough. It still counts as a rejected edit that is shown in my stats though.

[This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381501/13485806) (and its duplicate), they both focus on whether or not that kind of "rejected edit" counts towards a ban. Spoiler alert: it does not. That's not my concern though. I would like to know why it still shows in my editor stats as a rejected edit as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Editor stats]

<sup>(Yes, this was my only reject edit)</sup>

Can we have suggested edits that end up in this situation not count as rejected edits (or at least not show in the stats) because nobody actually rejected them?

Comment: FWIW, this happens because a > 2k user overrides the edit outside of the queue.

Comment: Related [7 year old MSE feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171469), but it received no official reply.

Comment: @10Rep Thanks. Yes, I'm aware of that.

Comment: @JeanneDark Well, hopefully this time we can have a better response.

Comment: This has been asked [quitte a few times before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/290903?lq=1).

Comment: Interestingly enough when a edit is rolled back while a suggested edit is pending, [it gets marked as invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64041611/timeline) instead of rejected.

Comment: This is why I no longer edit.. I do not understand why Stack chooses to punish users this way. I guess one of those 345583 edit rejections is yours and one of them is mine ;)

Comment: @Scratte will you join us, poor editors, again once you gain 61 more rep? :)

Comment: @OlegValter Not likely, no. I was livid when I realized my profile had been tainted. Then I found several old feature-requests, like this one, that's gone ignored. I've uBlocked the edit option.

Comment: @Scratte - yeah, the edit rejection because of an overwrite is not the best way to go  (and surprisingly unaddressed... I guess, line-height changes are more important). Still, so much more fun after 2K :) Oh, btw, at the very least it is *status-review* for a couple of months, so the chances are not nil